# Delphi FMX OnGuard Undeclared identifier: 'TLbKey'

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, onguard

I am trying to implement OnGuard in my FireMonkey application, but the procedure below requires `TLbKey`. I tried installing both LockBox2 and LockBox3, I included `LbCipher`, but I always get an error:

> Undeclared identifier: 'TLbKey'

```
procedure TFolderForm.OgRegistrationCode1GetKey(Sender: TObject;
  var Key: TLbKey);
const CKey: TLbKey = ($E5, $8F, $84, $D6, $92, $C9, $A4, $D8, $1A, $FA, $6F, $8D, $AB, $FC, $DF, $B4);
begin
  Key := CKey;
end;
```

Comment: Why FMX and not vcl? You cannot use it on Android it uses Window computer for guard

Comment: I need it for MACOS

Comment: As far as I know, it checks PC under window ELECTRONICS for guarding the software. Be sure it does the job for MAC

Comment: OnGuard uses Windows API functions for PC identification, as well as some x86 assembly code, IIRC, which means it will not work on any OS other than Windows running on Intel-compatible CPUs. However, an unknown identifier error like that means that you're missing a unit in your uses clause or you have a typo in your identifier. Check the OnGuard documentation or source code to find out where TLbKey is defined, and add that unit to your uses clause. You can use the IDE's Search->Find in Files to search that source.

Comment: This code is not suited for your needs There are other codes that are software only that you might use.